# How do I add an if/else statement in this if/else statement?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

I need some help figuring out how I can modify this code:

```js
export const CommentsListBeijing = ({ comments }) => (
  if (comments.length > 0 ) {
    <ButtonToolbar className="comment-list">
    {comments.map((com) => (
      <CommentsModal key={ com._id } comment={ com } city={com.city} person={com.person} location={com.location} title={com.title} content={com.content} fileLink={com.fileLink} timestamp={com.timestamp} createdBy={com.createdBy}/>
    ))}
  </ButtonToolbar> :
  <Alert bsStyle="warning">No sparks yet. Please add some!</Alert>
);
```

I would like to add an If/Else statement within the mapping function.

So

```
if (com.adminSpark == true) { do something }
else 
do current
```

I am new to this way of writing an if/else statement and don't know how to combine the two.

Thanks for the help so far! I have been trying to add the else/if statement based on the feedback I received but I keep getting an error where the statement begins: "imports/ui/components/beijing/comments-list-beijing.js:16:2: Unexpected token (16:2)".

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'll like a one-liner, I'll go with tenary.

```
export const CommentsListBeijing = ({ comments }) => (
  if (comments.length > 0 ) {
    <ButtonToolbar className="comment-list">
    {comments.map((com) => (
      return com.adminSpark ? /* return something admin-related */ :      <CommentsModal key={ com._id } comment={ com } city={com.city} person={com.person} location={com.location} title={com.title} content={com.content} fileLink={com.fileLink} timestamp={com.timestamp} createdBy={com.createdBy}/>
    ))}
  </ButtonToolbar> :
  <Alert bsStyle="warning">No sparks yet. Please add some!</Alert>
 }
);
```

Although to improve readability of this code, I'd rather it looks something like:

```
export const CommentsListBeijing = ({ comments }) => (
  if (comments.length > 0 ) {
    <ButtonToolbar className="comment-list">
    {comments.map((com) => (
      return com.adminSpark ? 
        /* something admin-related */ : 
        <CommentsModal 
          key={ com._id } 
          comment={ com } 
          city={com.city} 
          person={com.person} 
          location={com.location} 
          title={com.title} 
          content={com.content} 
          fileLink={com.fileLink} 
          timestamp={com.timestamp} 
          createdBy={com.createdBy} />
    ))}
    </ButtonToolbar> :
    <Alert bsStyle="warning">No sparks yet. Please add some!</Alert>
   }
 );
```

Code that's easier to read almost always gets more valuable than one which is just 'concise'. My two cents though :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! For some reason I keep getting an error where the if statements begins: 
"imports/ui/components/beijing/comments-list-beijing.js:16:2: Unexpected token (16:2)"

How come?

Comment: Btw line 16 refers to the place where "if (comments.length > 0 ) {" starts.

Comment: Yeah I guessed as much. You need to close the brace for the if. I'd edit the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
export const CommentsListBeijing = ({ comments }) => (
  if (comments.length > 0 ) {
    <ButtonToolbar className="comment-list">
    {comments.map((com) => (
      if (com.adminSpark) {
        // do and return something;
      } else {
        return <CommentsModal key={ com._id } comment={ com } city={com.city} person={com.person} location={com.location} title={com.title} content={com.content} fileLink={com.fileLink} timestamp={com.timestamp} createdBy={com.createdBy}/>
      }
    ))}
  </ButtonToolbar> :
  <Alert bsStyle="warning">No sparks yet. Please add some!</Alert>
);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, so it is not possible with the new "one-line" statement?

Comment: Of course it is, but that version is easier to understand and more flexible than this:

`return com.adminSpark ? /* something else */ : <CommentsModal key={ com._id } comment={ com } city={com.city} person={com.person} location={com.location} title={com.title} content={com.content} fileLink={com.fileLink} timestamp={com.timestamp} createdBy={com.createdBy}/>`

Comment: Hmmm... When trying to implement the code I get an error: "imports/ui/components/beijing/comments-list-beijing.js:23:8: Unexpected token (23:8)" 

This refers to the part where the if statement begins. I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

I think,this will help :

```js
  if (comments.length > 0 ) {
    <ButtonToolbar className="comment-list">
    {comments.map((com) => (
      if (com.adminSpark==true) or if (com.adminSpark){
        // your code ;
      } else {
        return <CommentsModal key={ com._id } comment={ com } city={com.city} person={com.person} location={com.location} title={com.title} content={com.content} fileLink={com.fileLink} timestamp={com.timestamp} createdBy={com.createdBy}/>
      }
    ))}
  </ButtonToolbar>
```